# Azure BLOB upload - how to do it best way?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We're developing a web-application with Azure and the question is - how to upload into BLOB large images effectively directly from browser and make it secure and reliable?

Probably, we're experiencing bad performance because we're from Russia and currently using a trial Azure. Maybe with the full subscription this problem will go away?

Anyway, my concern is that our application has to pass our image through the following path:

```
WebBrowser > (image.jpg) > Azure WebRole [store name in DB] > (image.jpg) > Azure BLOB
```

So there is an overhead involving WebRole. What I'd like to do is to upload my large file to BLOB directly and send image name to WebRole in parallel:

```
WebBrowser > (image.jpg) > Azure BLOB
WebBrowser > WebRole [store name in DB]
```

The problem here is security. I'm talking about uploading user pictures and don't want hackers being able to write into one's container.

Is it reasonable at all?

Comment: I guess, that my location must not affect the performance, because WebRole and BLOB should work fine with each other I guess.

Comment: For a good sample, you might want to check out http://blobshare.codeplex.com/ it has a silverlight multi file uploader and just regular file uploading.  It also has configurable permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverlight is an option, using Shared Access Signatures (special URLs that allow write access on a time-limited basis). See my series of blog posts: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/uploading-windows-azure-blobs-from-silverlight-part-1-shared-access-signatures

Comment: Well, it's a good alternative. I'm currently looking forward utilizing this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

+1 for @smarx's suggestion of uploading via Shared Access Signature - that offers a time-limited URL that lets you access a private blob as if it were public. Someone would need to be running a network sniffer to attempt to discover an SAS-encoded URL, and even then, it would only be valid for a short period of time.

Just wanted to add that having a trial subscription is no different from a paid subscription, when it comes to performance. That's just a billing thing and has nothing to do with resource allocation.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I also thought that a trial subscription must not affect performance, but it does. Not directly but by restricting areas where my Hosted Services might be deployed. I'm from Russia, Saint-Petersburg and able to deploy only in Asia and SE Asia. Not in Europe which is closer to me. This is probably the cause of long request/response.